# Open_basedir errors - But setting basedir to none redults in 502 Bad Gateway

Tags: plugins, php, errors

I'm getting open-basedir errors from various plugins, such as *updraft plus* and *super cache*.

Changing open-basedir to "none" from PHP options resulted in a 502 error. I'm noticing that all the paths throwing errors for updraft plus are /:/tmp, if that's relevant.

Edit: updraft plus seems to contain a .htaccess in its folder with "deny from all" on it.

Thank you

Comment: Sorry, but third party code (like plugins) are off topic here. You can ask via their official support forums instead.

Comment: Looks like a more server configuration than WordPress itself. Seem like there's problem with access rights to some directories, probably related to rights which you web server is running.